# Did a layout with many ui controls can support pinch and zoom gestures

Tags: android, zooming, android-3.0-honeycomb

I need apply pinch and zoom gestures for my complete view.
In my view there are `a lot of controls` like textviews, buttons, list view and all. This all have `different listeners`. I need to `apply zoom` to this `without affecting` the my `UI controls and listeners`.
I know how to zoom a image and using a webview. But how **we apply zoom to complete layout with different controls and listeners**  ?
(I'm working on **honeycomb**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last i got the solution. We can use setScalaX and setScaleY with pivot point
I have explained it here
[Zooming a view completely](http://myandroidnote.blogspot.com/2011/03/zooming-view-completely.html)
[Pinch Zoom to view completely](http://myandroidnote.blogspot.com/2011/03/pinch-zoom-to-view-completely.html)

Comment: Hi, I have used the above code but while Pinch zoom the view get flicker. pls tell me how to avoid the flickerring of views in your source code.

Answer (score 0):

Im not aware of anything that will simply take care of this. All I can say is that I've known others to achieve this by applying a translation matrix to a route view group which then applies to it's children's views (if I remember correctly).

From this the touch events were converted to apply to the translated view.

To handle the pinch to zoom this may be of use: [Android Dev - OnScaleGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener.html)

Comment: how can we applying a *translation matrix to a route view group*

Comment: Yeah I have achieved it by using `ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener`.